Visualize distribution of continuous values for a column of Dataframe
I have a Pandas dataframe. It contains a column that is named "Label". I want to see the distribution of Labels. labels are numeric and continuous. I want a plot in Python that shows the distribution of Label values.
I want a Python code for plotting the distribution of labels.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You could use Dataframe.plot.kde to generate a plot of the continuous distribution:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mu, sigma = 10, 3
distribution = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Label" : distribution})
df.plot.kde()

